# stdout to log, stderr to log and console

Tags: bash

I'm trying to send all output to a log, with stderr also displaying in the console.

..with the log entries in order and some method to send comments to the log+console (same as stderr).

```
exec &> log
```

For instance, this doesn't work:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 2> >(tee log) 2>&1 > build.log

echo "Yes 1"
ugh "No 1"
echo "Yes 2"
ugh "No 2"
echo "Message to user" 3>&1
```

The examples I'm finding here and elsewhere either put them out of order or redirect both to log and console.

None of the examples send all output to the log - with stderr and 'special messages' also displayed on screen...

**Solution**

Chris solved this in his answer below. This is the adapted solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 3> >(tee -a log)
exec 4>>log
exec >&4 2>&3

# Out: To log.
echo "I'm standard output."

# Error: To log and console.
ugh "command not found"

# Message: To log and console.
echo "Message to user." >&3
```

This writes the to the log / console as the given comment suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this is to be done in a script? If so, this should do what you want, I think. `stdout` will be sent only to `out.txt`. `stderr` will be sent to the console and to `err.txt`

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 3> >(tee ./err.txt)
exec 4>./out.txt
exec >&4 2>&3

echo "I'm normal text!"    # only in out.txt
echo "I'm an error!" >&2   # in err.txt and on console
```

**Edit:** I'm disturbingly pleased with myself for this little script, and I'm not quite sure why.

**Edit 2:** To write both streams to the same file, simply use the same filename in both places. In theory, this could rarely cause a loss of ordering between stdout and stderr; in practice it's close enough. (See my rambling comment below for more.)

Comment: Works (adjusted to write to one file)! If I don't have the reputation, will someone upvote this?

Comment: If you use the same filename for both streams, you will get that effect. The message ordering will be preserved in *effectively* all cases. That being said, in some extremely rare cases, absolute ordering may be lost on a very small number of cases (if the CPU schedules the various threads *just right* and messages come from both pipes at *exactly* the same time and the `tee` is preempted by a stdout write that completes before tee resumes...). In practice, since I/O is pretty atomic, I would consider the occurrence of this to be effectively never.

Comment: Also, even if you can't upvote, you should be able to accept it as an answer, correct? With the checkmark icon.

Comment: Yep lol - Accepted, and thank you!! Updated my question to reflect your answer adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

You can swap the stdout and the stderr stream. see this example:

```
ps aux 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 | grep init
```

Check out [this link](https://linuxacademy.com/blog/linux/tutorial-the-best-tips-tricks-for-bash-explained/) for more detail.

Comment: Tried, but no-go for what I'm trying to do, thank you though!